# Knockout data-binding to viewModel

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have this view:

```
@model Store.WebUI.Models.CartIndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Your Cart";
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>

<h2>Your cart</h2>
<table id="cartTable" class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th class="text-right">Price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Lines">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Quantity"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Product.Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Product.Price"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And for some reason values are not binding to the table columns, even though during debug in Chrome I can see that the variable "data" in my script looks like this:

```
var data = {"Cart":{"Lines":[{"Product":{"ProductId":2,"Name":"Game","Description":"Some Game","Category":"Games","Price":29.99},"Quantity":1}]},"ReturnUrl":"/Games"};
```

I am new to knockout and jQuery in general and I can't understand what am I missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe your object structure:

```
{
  "Cart": {
    "Lines": [...]
  }
}
```

The point to note is that `Lines` is within `Cart`. Since you don't tell KO how to navigate there, nothing appears on the screen. You could solve the issue like this:

```
<table id="cartTable" class="table" data-bind="with: Cart">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th class="text-right">Price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Lines">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Quantity"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Product.Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Product.Price"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Note the `data-bind="with: Cart"` binding. This causes KO to use the embedded `Cart` object as the binding context, and voila, `Lines` becomes a valid reference.

You also need to download the KO Mapping plugin from [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) or the call to `ko.mapping.fromJS` will fail.

Comment: OMG, this makes so much sense!

Comment: Wait, but shouldn't it be viewModel.Cart? Simple data-binding to Cart doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Is there a good way to debug view to track values that are being bound?

Comment: It works for me in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rzso11jL/ However, If I use `ko.mapping.fromJS` as you did, I get an error, as seen in the console. Personally, I've never used that helper, so I cannot add too much to that.

Comment: `viewModel.Cart` is not good, because it is the `viewModel` variable itself that is the _binding root_. In other words, it is the top of the object structure KO can see; KO doesn't see your global variables. To that end, you cannot reference `viewModel`...

Comment: ... This is because you passed the `viewModel` variable to `applyBindings`. So whatever you pass to that method becomes your binding root and whatever property name you use must exist in that object. For example, if you passed `window` (to say something stupid) then yes, you'd need to navigate into `Cart` as well.

Comment: To add to the `mapping` part of the question, what I can see is that if I log `ko` itself to the console it does not show anything like `mapping`, perhaps where you've see that was from an external library?

Edit: yes, it is a plugin, downloadable from here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html I've updated my answer to sum it up.

Comment: Thanks for all you input. The problem (after your first reply) was much simpler. Script was placed in the beginning, instead of in the end.